# Show spinner/loader after posting and while external page(s) load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spinner, response, postback

My end goal is to show a spinner/loader after a postback while the page reloads, and while the redirect loads.

I'm not having an issue showing the spinner while the current page submits the form, but then it reloads after a postback and the spinner dissapears. Then, it redirects to an external page. During this postback and redirect, there can be a few seconds of a blank white screen that I want to show a spinner during.

I will try to give some code as an example.

This bit shows the loader just fine after the button is clicked:

```
//CSS
.overlay-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(../Images/hd-spinner.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

//JS
function showLoader() {
    var overlay = '<div class="overlay-spinner"></div>';
    jQuery(overlay).appendTo('html');
}

//asp.net button
<asp:Button ID="bMakePayment" TabIndex="30" runat="server" OnClick="bMakePayment_Click" Text="Make Payment" OnClientClick="showLoader();"/>
```

But then the page reloads, and the bMakePayment_Click fires on the server-side which in turn calls this:

```
private void HTTPPostForm(string content, string url)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write("<html><head></head>");
    Response.Write("<body onload='document.newForm.submit();'>");
    Response.Write("<form name='newForm' target='_parent' method='POST' action='" + url + "'>");
    Response.Write(string.Format("<input type='hidden' name='PWREQUEST' value='{0}' />", base64Encode(content)));
    Response.Write("</form>");
    Response.Write("</body></html>");
    Response.End();
}
```

Now while this happens, it eventually redirects to another page, but there are a few seconds of a while screen on my page and the external page. This is where I can't figure out how to show the spinner.

I've tried sending this response to an iframe to load the result there (by changing the target), but then it will load the external page in a new tab, and show this response in the same window, instead of in the iframe on my original page.

I think I'm not fully understanding the process at hand, so let me know if you need more of my code.

Comment: I don't think you can, the page from where the redirect takes place is unloaded and the next page still needs to be loaded. There is nothing in between that can show a spinner except the browser program itself.

Comment: What if I load the the response in an iframe, is that possible? Then, I can show the spinner from the main body.

Comment: Possible, but then your visitor will stay in the iframe, which is bad practice. And if you break out of the frame when the other page is loaded it will still show a white screen for a moment because the page is reloaded and you will have the same problem.